# invalid character in app.yaml and wp-config.php in app engine Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have followed the process described in the github project for wordpress on google app engine and everything went well on my local machine and I was able to set it up locally but on deploying it to app engine, I got illegal characters errors which might be the reason that I get a NOT FOUND error when i try to run the wp-admin/install.php.

```
11:21 AM Getting current resource limits.
11:21 AM Scanning files on local disk.
2014-09-11 11:21:16,836 ERROR appcfg.py:1912 Invalid character in filename: app.yaml~ 
2014-09-11 11:21:16,898 ERROR appcfg.py:1912 Invalid character in filename: wp-config.php~ 
2014-09-11 11:21:16,901 ERROR appcfg.py:1912 Invalid character in filename: wordpress/wp-config.php~ 
11:21 AM Scanned 500 files.
11:21 AM Scanned 1000 files.
2014-09-11 11:21:17,261 ERROR appcfg.py:2514 Ignoring file '.git/objects/pack/pack-659e3e13f34cac5e023fd14bf3479a2fa77da146.pack': Too long (max 32000000 bytes, file is 65085974 bytes). 
2014-09-11 11:21:17,297 ERROR appcfg.py:2514 Ignoring file '.git/modules/wordpress/objects/pack/pack-70ed9c08282cfff33b47d644d4b2b3f6b7083123.pack': Too long (max 32000000 bytes, file is 103993167 bytes). 
11:21 AM Cloning 659 static files.
11:21 AM Cloning 1443 application files.
11:21 AM Uploading 1 files and blobs.
11:21 AM Uploaded 1 files and blobs
11:21 AM Compilation starting.
11:21 AM Compilation completed.
11:21 AM Starting deployment.
11:21 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
11:21 AM Deployment successful.
11:21 AM Checking if updated app version is serving.
11:21 AM Completed update of app:
```

I used the default app.yaml file that came with the project code and here is the contents of the app.yaml file

```
application: reliable-jet-694
version: wpfromstarterproject
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm|html|css|js))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm|html|css|js)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif))$
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico|jpg|png|gif)$
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php

skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?\.zip$
- ^(.*/)?\.bat$
- ^(.*/)?\.sh$
- ^(.*/)?\.md$
```

I will be really grateful if someone could help me as I am in a hurry to deploy this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was not with the invalid character but I had two versions and the non wordpress version was selected as the default, Changing the settings worked well in my case.